# Trying to figure out auth0 custom login screen callback url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, auth0

I've been trying to follow [this](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angularjs/02-custom-login) guide to get my custom login screen to work with my angular app locally. The part i'm struggling on is my login callback never gets called.

My original login url is `http://localhost:9000/#/login`

```
angular.module('myApp').service('authService', function ($location, angularAuth0) {

    function login(username, password, callback) {
        console.log('in login service');
    angularAuth0.login({
      connection: 'Username-Password-Authentication',
      responseType: 'token',
      email: username,
      password: password
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('we NEVER get here');
    });
  }

    return {
      login: login
    };

});


angular.module('myApp').controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $location, authService) {

    $scope.login = function() {
        ...
        authService.login($scope.user.email, $scope.user.password)
```

When i login, I get redirected to `http://localhost:9000/#/access_token<myaccesstoken>&id_token=<myIdToken>&token_type=Bearer`

Why do i get redirected to this url and my callback never get called?

Also when am i supposed to use this function `authenticateAndGetProfile()` which they create in the guide?

Comment: Is your auth0.service.js like this one: https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angularjs-sample/blob/master/02-Custom-Login/components/auth/auth.service.js?
In https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angularjs-sample/tree/master/02-Custom-Login you have a working sample, does it work for you?

Comment: Yes as you can see my login function in authService is the same. I have not tried to clone the sample and run it. One thing i notice is that the method `authenticateAndGetProfile` never gets called from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Ok in working with the Auth0 support team, it seems that their documentation was missing this section which has since been added:

```
Register the authenticateAndGetProfile in app.run.js so that authentication results get processed after login.

// app.run.js

(function () {

  'use strict';

  angular
  .module('app')
  .run(function (authService) {

  // Process the auth token if it exists and fetch the profile
  authService.authenticateAndGetProfile();
  });

})();
```

That was the missing piece and now everything works.